# finding which index of an object a subset is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object.

```
(object.array)
```

the object looks like this.

```
object[0](id=one, person=person1, action=action1);
object[1](id=two, person=person2, action=action2);
object[2](id=three, person=person3, action=action3);
```

Now I want to know how to look up which index of object I'm in when I have the ID (which is unique for every array).

i.e. 
id="one" is a part of object[?].

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: iterate the object, compare your id against the existing element within the iteration, if they're equal, grab that index.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. So all I need to do is run a for - in loop and check the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function such as the following, to iterate through the array and return the index or `-1` if right index was not found:

```
var getIndex = function( id ) {
    var index = -1;
    $.each(o, function(i,v) {
        if( v.id == id ) {
            index = i;
            return false; //break out of .each
        }
    });
    return index;
}

console.log( getIndex( 'three' ) ); //output: 2
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/KY23R/)